# Как сделать запрос интервал дат

Tags: php

В mysql лежит дата в таком виде `2019-11-27 10:50:21`

Я делаю выборку вот так:

```
$date=date("-m-");

$query = "select * from test where date like '%".$date."%'";
$result = $conn1->query($query);
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$arr2[]=$row2;
}
```

Как сделать это по другому или точнее по правильному?

Comment: все зависит от того, что вы понимаете по интервалом. Но в любом случае данный столбец  должен иметь тип datetime. Если надо за месяц, то вычисляете начало и конец месяца, и пишите запрос с `between`. либо для ленивых `year(d) = 2019 and month(d) = ...` (но это гораздо менее эффективно, в случае если у вас есть индекс по дате)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20  MINUTE)
```